# What do I need to do to have both C++/CLI and unmanaged C++11 enum classes?

Tags: c++11, enums, c++-cli

The new enum class type in C++11 came from the C++/CLI version with the same name but they are quite different and are causing me problems.

I have a library written in C++11 containing several structures like (really simplified here):

```
// File.h

enum class MyEnum : unsigned int
{
   Val1,
   Val2
};

struct MyStruct
{
    MyEnum value;
    MyStruct(MyEnum v) : value(v) {}
};
```

I am trying to reach this code from a C++/CLI class library to expose it to .NET. I include the file like this:

```
#pragma unmanaged
#include "File.h"
#pragma managed
```

The problem is that the enum constructor yields a compile error message like:

```
error C3821: 'v': managed type or function cannot be used in an unmanaged function
```

suggesting that the compiler still interprets the enum class as a C++/CLI enum class even though I am within the unmanaged section and it really should interpret it as a C++11 enum class. Is there anything I can do about this?

EDIT: I am using VS2012. Please let me know if VS2013 fixes this.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in a standalone test app. With *or without* the `#pragma unmanaged`, `MyEnum` ends up as an unmanaged enum. I was only able to get `MyEnum` to be managed by putting either `public` or `private` in front of the word `enum`. (Access specifiers are only valid on managed types.) Do you have an access specifier in your code that you didn't copy-paste here?

Comment: Actually I was not able to get an error when I tried just now in an isolated project either. However I found that the error in the bigger project could be resolved by not forward declaring the enum class (it turns out I did this). But trying both versions (forward-declared vs not forward-declared) in the isolated project worked. I guess something about include order confised the compiler.

Comment: @DavidYaw see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem in VS2013. In my case, I'm including an unmanaged `enum class` but the compiler is generating errors because it thinks it's a managed `enum class`. With the help from the comments on the question, I was able to fix it by removing all forward declarations of the enum. It looks like this is a compiler bug, where the forward declaration ignores the `#pragma unmanaged` directive.

I've created an example of how to reproduce the bug here:

```
#pragma managed(push, off)

enum class TestEnum
{
    One,
    Two,
    Three,
};

#include <vector>

enum class TestEnum; // Forward declaration after actual declaration causes the bug

#pragma managed(pop)

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    // error C3699: '&&' : cannot use this indirection on type 'TestEnum'
    std::vector<TestEnum> enums;

    return 0;
}
```

I've reported the issue to Microsoft here:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1218131